# Can I apply for a long term visit visa after being denied entryto UK? Would the odds be in my favour?

Tags: uk, long-term

I worked in the UK for the last couple of years on a Tier 2 visa but moved to another country recently. I tried to re-enter the country during the curtailment period unaware that the visa was not valid (although a part of the curtailment letter said I had leave to enter until the curtailment period).I was denied entry and removed from the UK. Can I apply for a long term visa directly or do I need to apply for a 6-month visa first (since this is recommended to see your international travel history)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems pretty obvious you have to start with baby steps. Your chances of a long term visa are slim. Your chances of getting any visa are slim, so why throw more money on an expensive long term visa?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have an academic collaborator in the UK and  need to frequently visit the UK from Europe.

Comment: @Mart6 You are of course free to apply for a standard visit visa or the long term version (were you thinking of 2, 5, or even 10years?). However based on your description of your circumstances your chances seem slim to non-existent. You would need a watertight application, including a credible premise for the visit and strong ties to your country of residence, which seems unlikely given you say you’ve only recently moved there. You’d do better to forget about the UK for a while and concentrate on building up a travel history elsewhere.

Comment: `I forgot to mention that I have an academic collaborator in the UK and need to frequently visit the UK from Europe` Does not change your situation. People also have family in the UK they want to visit and get denied all the time. Academic collaboration is nothing compared to that.

Comment: Academic collaboration could be done via Skype, I’m not convinced it’s a permitted activity under the Immigration Rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules Your description sounds very much like you want to renter for work.

Comment: @Traveller It depends on the field of work, I think. Coming to, e.g., do experiments in a lab would be one thing but if you came to collaborate with me, nobody would be able to tell the difference between that and any other business meeting.

Comment: @Giorgio I'm not sure this is really a duplicate. Being refused entry for breaching visa restrictions seems like it might be different to being refused for bringing too much of a restricted good.

Comment: @DavidRicherby you may be right, although what one must do afterwards is the same.... I may have to dig deep and respond to the Q :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the response. I happen to have a very strong premise but will apply for the standard visa and see how it goes :)

Answer (score 1):

What is most relevant is curtailment: for whatever reason, the conditions under  which you were allowed to be in the UK were no longer valid and your leave to *enter or remain* was cancelled. Your [Home Office curtailment notice](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/520008/Curtailmentv16.0.pdf) would have set forth the terms and parameters. You had to depart the UK and, once you did, you could not enter the country, as you no longer held a valid visa.

You certainly can apply for a [Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) but a decision on its issuance and length of validity would rest with UKVI, not with you, and would take into consideration your immigration history.